# Can I add python script to SPSS Modeler 16?

Tags: python, analytics, jython, spss, spss-modeler

I'm trying to build an analytic model with `SPSS Modeler 16.0` and there is some parts that are easy to do with `Python`. Now my question is what are the limits for using `python` or `jython` scripting in SPSS ?
Can I import all the libraries that I want as well as in a classic python program ?

Answer (score 0):

Modeler scripting uses Jython, not standard Python, but you should be able to load any library that is compatible with Jython.

SPSS Statistics uses standard Python 2.7

Comment: thanks for the reply @JKP but in `Jython` we can't load the libraries like `Numpy` or `Scipy` am I wrong ?

Comment: Those libraries are built for standard Python and will not work with Jython, inside Modeler or outside.